# Graphite — filter out N latest datapoints?

Tags: graphite

Is there a way to filter out the N latest data points of Graphite series?

The latest data points contain incomplete data and I want to filter them out. Timeshift does not cut it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use relative time in the render query by modifying `from/until` as needed, that might help. https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html#from-until

If it's only the most recent few datapoints you want to ignore, but if it's some data in the middle of the range, that wont work. If the data you want to omit our outliers of some sort, with values exceeding or far below the other data, you could use something like removeAbove/BelowValue or removeAbove/BelowPercentile: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.removeAbovePercentile

Comment: `Until` parameter doesn't cut it as well, here's why: I want to use `summarize(1m, sum, false)` in my query. The problem is: say I run this query at 00h10m20s without specifying until parameter (so, until=now). Obviously, the last data point will contain incomplete count, because only 20s passed since 00h10m00s. And when I run it with `until=-1m`, my last data point again contains incomplete data, because only 20s passed after 00h09m00s...

I know that the problem can be partially fixed by using alignToFrom=true, but it brings its own disadvantages.